# D3.JS V4 update chart elements after adding/updating data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build simple line chart using d3.js V4.
I've got basic concept from multiple bl.ocks samples.

My idea is to create char and then add data to it, with max 9 data points.

Here is view of what I've build so far:

[image]

I'm able to update line using this:

```
addValue: function(val) {
    chartData.push(val);

    if (chartData.length > 9) {
        chartData.shift();
    }

    y.domain([
    -2,
    d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
      return d + 2;
    })
    ]);

    var svg = element.transition();
    svg
    .select(".d3-line")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", valueline(chartData));
}
```

but I also want to add/move point and lines when I add new data, without this my buggy chart looks like this:

[image]

I'm adding initial points and lines using this code:

```
var lineGuides = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll(".d3-line-guides-group")
  .data(chartData);

lineGuides
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "d3-line-guides")
  .attr("x1", function(t, e) {
    return x(e);
  })
  .attr("y1", function(t, a) {
    return height;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(t, e) {
    return x(e);
  })
  .attr("y2", function(t, a) {
    return height;
  })
  .style("stroke", "rgba(255,255,255,0.3)")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "4,2")
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(function(t, x) {
    return 150 * x;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(t) {
    return y(t);
  })
  .transition();

var points = svg
  .insert("g")
  .selectAll(".d3-line-circle")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "d3-line-circle d3-line-circle-medium")
  .attr("cx", function(t, e) {
    return x(e);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(t) {
    return y(t);
  })
  .attr("r", 3)
  .style("stroke", "#fff")
  .style("fill", "#29B6F6")
  .on("mouseover", function(t) {
    d3
      .select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("r", 5);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(t) {
    d3
      .select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("r", 3);
  });
points
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(250)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
  .delay(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

How can I add new points and update old when data changes?

Here is code that I have so far:

```
/* global window, define, module */
(function(global, factory) {
  var MicroChart = factory(global);
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD support
    define(function() {
      return MicroChart;
    });
  } else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS support
    module.exports = MicroChart;
  } else {
    // We are probably running in the browser
    global.MicroChart = MicroChart;
  }
})(typeof window === "undefined" ? this : window, function(global, undefined) {
  var document = global.document;
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  var MicroChart = (function() {
    var defaultOptions = {
      height: 50
    };

    function shallowCopy(/* source, ...targets*/) {
      var target = arguments[0],
        sources = slice.call(arguments, 1);
      sources.forEach(function(s) {
        for (k in s) {
          if (s.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            target[k] = s[k];
          }
        }
      });
      return target;
    }

    return function MicroChart(elem, opts) {
      opts = shallowCopy({}, defaultOptions, opts);
      var gaugeContainer = elem,
        chartHeigh = opts.height,
        instance;

      var xScale, yScale, valueline, x, y;
      var chartData = [5, 8, 2];
      var element;


      function initializeMicroChart(elem, height) {
        element = d3.select(elem);

        var margins = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 };
        var width =
          element.node().getBoundingClientRect().width -
          margins.left -
          margins.right;
        var height = chartHeigh - margins.top - margins.bottom;

        var l = 10;

        x = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, 8])
          .range([l, width - l]);

        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        valueline = d3
          .line()
          .x(function(d, i) {
            console.log(i);
            return x(i);
          })
          .y(function(d) {
            return y(d);
          });

        var svg = element
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margins.left + margins.right)
          .attr("height", height + margins.top + margins.bottom);

        y.domain([
          -2,
          d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
            return d + 2;
          })
        ]);


      var s4 =function() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
          .toString(16)
          .substring(1);
      }


        var guid = s4()+s4();
        console.log(guid);

        var path = svg
          .append("path")
          .data([chartData])
          .attr("class", "d3-line d3-line-medium")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#"+guid+")")
          .attr("d", valueline)
          .style("stroke", "#fff");

        var clipPath = svg
          .append("defs")
          .append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", guid);

        var rect = clipPath
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "clip")
          .attr("width", 0)
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("transform", null)
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
          .attr("width", width);

        var lineGuides = svg
          .append("g")
          .selectAll(".d3-line-guides-group")
          .data(chartData);

        lineGuides
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .attr("class", "d3-line-guides")
          .attr("x1", function(t, e) {
            return x(e);
          })
          .attr("y1", function(t, a) {
            return height;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(t, e) {
            return x(e);
          })
          .attr("y2", function(t, a) {
            return height;
          })
          .style("stroke", "rgba(255,255,255,0.3)")
          .style("stroke-dasharray", "4,2")
          .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .delay(function(t, x) {
            return 150 * x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(t) {
            return y(t);
          })
          .transition();

        var points = svg
          .insert("g")
          .selectAll(".d3-line-circle")
          .data(chartData)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "d3-line-circle d3-line-circle-medium")
          .attr("cx", function(t, e) {
            return x(e);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(t) {
            return y(t);
          })
          .attr("r", 3)
          .style("stroke", "#fff")
          .style("fill", "#29B6F6")
          .on("mouseover", function(t) {
            d3
              .select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(250)
              .attr("r", 5);
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(t) {
            d3
              .select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(250)
              .attr("r", 3);
          });
        points
          .style("opacity", 0)
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
          .delay(1000)
          .style("opacity", 1);
      }
      instance = {
        addValue: function(val) {
          chartData.push(val);

          if (chartData.length > 9) {
            chartData.shift();
          }

          y.domain([
            -2,
            d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
              return d + 2;
            })
          ]);

          var svg = element.transition();
          svg
            .select(".d3-line")
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(chartData));
        }
      };

      initializeMicroChart(gaugeContainer, chartHeigh);
      return instance;
    };
  })();

  return MicroChart;
});

var gauge1 = MicroChart(document.getElementById("chart1"));

var gauge2 = MicroChart(document.getElementById("chart2"), {
  height: 70
});

var randomInt = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

$("#update").on("click", function() {
  gauge1.addValue(randomInt(5, 15));
  gauge2.addValue(randomInt(5, 15));
});
```

And here is codepen to see my code in action: https://codepen.io/Misiu/pen/dmGyZW?editors=0010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.enter().append()` to add new nodes, `.merge()` to merge existing and appended nodes, then update all nodes and call `.exit().remove()` to remove unnecessary nodes. So, you could use following update pattern:

```js
d3.select(window).on('load', function() {
  // Join data
  var joined = d3.select('div').selectAll('p').data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  joined
  // Add new elements
    .enter().append('p')
  // Merge both new and existing elements 
    .merge(joined)
  // Update new and existing elements 
    .text(d => d);
  // Remove excess elements
  joined.exit().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

As result, the two `<p>` elements will be created and all `<p>` elements will be updated.

See also [General Update Pattern, I](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I won't have to remove nodes. Most of the time I will have to add new and then only update dots position Same with dotted lines. I'll try to work something out and share my results

Comment: @Misiu, I have appended example to my answer. If you don't need to remove nodes, then you could ignore *Remove* part of the pattern.

Comment: This works perfect. Here is my current result: https://codepen.io/Misiu/pen/XEXmYm (click Add Bata in footer). Last thing missing is responsiveness, but that's another story :)